# With or without async await I am getting this error on returning result

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**With or without async await I am getting this error on returning result on line 26.
I am building a weather app but this is just a scratch file to test some things and concepts since I am learning from a Course called Flutter Beginner course. **

**Error:** *The non-nullable local variable 'resolt' must be assigned before it can be used.*

**Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';
 
void main() {
  performTasks();
}
 
void performTasks() async {
  task1();
  String newtask2Result = await task2();
  task3(newtask2Result);
}
 
void task1() {
  String result = 'task 1 data';
  print('Task 1 complete');
}
 
Future task2() async {
  Duration threeSeconds = Duration(seconds: 3);
  String resolt;
 
  await Future.delayed(threeSeconds, () {
    resolt = 'task 2 data';
    print('Task 2 complete');
  });
  return resolt;
}
 
void task3(String task2Data) {
  String result = 'task 3 data';
  print('Task 3 complete with $task2Data');
}
```

**Picture:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4b5T.png)

Comment: Your string should be initialized with some value before its usage. Assign empty string to it. String resolt = '';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In then `task2()` function, you are declaring a variable but not initializing it.

You can either initialize it with default value or make it of type `late`.

Example 1 - default value

```
Future task2() async {
  Duration threeSeconds = Duration(seconds: 3);
  String resolt = "";

  await Future.delayed(threeSeconds, () {
    resolt = 'task 2 data';
    print('Task 2 complete');
  });
  return resolt;
}
```

Example 2 - declaring as `late`

```
Future task2() async {
  Duration threeSeconds = Duration(seconds: 3);
  late String resolt;

  await Future.delayed(threeSeconds, () {
    resolt = 'task 2 data';
    print('Task 2 complete');
  });
  return resolt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it finally worked with using 'late' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Change your return type from Future to Future  .